# If condition with three cases and using Boolean variables

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm running into a problem with ifs, I have three possible functions to invoke, and these functions should be called based on a Boolean value
`public void depositaSoldi(){

```
    EditText editTextSoldiDepositati = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber_banca_soldi_depositare);
    Button buttonDepositaSoldi = findViewById(R.id.button_banca_deposita);
    buttonDepositaSoldi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            soldiDaDepositare = editTextSoldiDepositati.getText().toString();
            Log.d("soldi_depositati",""+soldiDaDepositare);
            editTextSoldiDepositati.setText("");
            double soldiDepositati = Double.parseDouble(soldiDaDepositare);
            //if(editTextEmpty)
            if(home.getSoldi() < soldiDepositati){

                Toast.makeText(Banca.this, "Soldi insufficienti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                home.setSoldi(home.getSoldi() - soldiDepositati);
                salvaDanaioBanca += soldiDepositati;
                Log.d("valore_soldi_attuale", "" + home.getSoldi());
                Log.d("valore_salvadanio", "" + salvaDanaioBanca);
                if(checkTassoElite == false){
                    aumentaSoldiTassoStandard();
                    aggiornaSoldi();

                } else if (checkTassoElite == true) {

                    aumentaSoldiTassoElite();
                    aggiornaSoldi();

                }
                
                else if(checkTassoPremium){
                    
                    //
                }

              

            }
        }
    });
}`
```

Rightly the last case does not see me because I am bound by the Boolean variable, because the last case sees a Boolean variable different from the first two cases, and I do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: When should that case be triggered? Is it independent from the value of `checkTassoElite`?

Comment: can you explain when these 3 will trigger?

Comment: `checkTassoElite == false`, `checkTassoElite == true` - one of those checks will pass, so you can't chain an `else` after them, it will never run! Are you sure you don't just want a plain `if`?

Comment: I don't understand the (natural) language, but to me it look like you are selling 3 payment plans: standard, elite, and premium. If so, why not use an _enum_?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca this case will start when a user watch ADS, (After clicking a button)

Comment: @AsadRehman the trigger start if you talk with a virtual director of a bank and you have the 15% of probability to increase your interest rate

Comment: @DanieleAnnese I was asking about the state of the world (i.e. the values of the various variables), not about user interaction :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have two `boolean` variables named `checkTassoElite` and `checkTassoPremium`.

What you'll want to do is this:

- If both are false, then it is "tasso standard".
- Else, if `checkTassoElite` is true, it is "tasso elite".
- Else, if `checkTassoPremium` is true, it is "tasso premium".

It should be fairly easy to convert the above rules to Java code.

Some notes:

- You don't need to write `if (something == true)`, if `something` is a `boolean` value. Just write `if (something)`.
- Likewise, you don't need to write `if (something == false)`. Use the `!` ("not") operator: `if (!something)`.
- Use `&&` (logical AND) to combine multiple criteria. For example: `if (something && somethingElse)` to check that both `something` and `somethingElse` are `true`.
- You can of course combine the use of `!` and `&&`, for example: `if (!something && !somethingElse)` which means: if both `something` and `somethingElse` are `false`.

Comment: Basically I have three types of interest rates, and based on certain events, a type of interest rate must be activated, the interest rates are checkTassoDiInteressePremium and checkTassoDiInteresseElite, the standard one I didn't use because I use it as a negation of the rate of interest. premium interest, only one of these must be activated, but obviously another can be activated during the execution of the application.



I tried to combine the conditions with the logical and, but by doing so none of the 3 cases worked anymore, while in the current state of the code 2 methods of 3 work

Comment: I solved, I don't understand why the -1 one cannot ask a question and you receive the - 1, the case of the conditions is not as simple as it may seem, but even if it was a trivial question, I don't understand why to put - 1 lol

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I initially tried to combine the conditions, but as they didn't work and not having enough faith in what I was doing, I thought it was not possible, you gave me the input to understand it was possible and in fact I solved the problem thanks thousand, of course I put the +1 on you (Jesper)